# Implementing min Heap using an array

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I am trying to implement min Heap in C.

```
// Heaps:
// node i -> 2i and 2i+1 children
// 2i//2 = i and 2i+1//2 = i same parents

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 100

int heap[max];
int size = 0;

void heapifyUp(){ // last element
    int i = size;

    while(i){ // 
        int parent = i/2;
        if (heap[parent]<heap[i]){
            int t = heap[parent];
            heap[parent] = heap[i];
            heap[i]=t;
        }        
    }
}

void heapifyDown(){ // top element
    int i = 0;

    while(i<=size){
        int c1 = 2*i;
        int c2 = 2*i + 1;
        int t = 0;
        if (heap[c1]>=heap[c2]){
            t = c2;
        }
        else{
            t = c1;
        }
        int temp = heap[i];
        heap[i] = heap[t];
        heap[t] = temp;
        i = t;
    }
}

void insert(int key){
    size = size + 1;
    heap[size] = key;
    heapifyUp();
}

int returnMin(){
    return heap[0];
}

int deleteMin(){
    int t = heap[0];
    heap[0] = heap[size];
    size = size - 1;
    heapifyDown();
    return t;
}

void printHeap(){

    int i = 0;
    while(i<=size){
        printf("%d",heap[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    insert(10);
    insert(20);
    insert(11);
    insert(7);
    insert(18);

    printHeap();
    printf("%d",deleteMin());

    insert(110);
    insert(-7);
    insert(15);

    printf("%d",deleteMin());
}
```

The issue is that when I run the program, I get no output and the program doesn't terminate.

I think i have implemented the logic correctly.

Using debugger with C is hard as I am on a Mac (doesn't support Codeblocks, never really understood how to use gdb, am just using the built-in gcc compiler on a text editor), so I am stuck in this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are writing this in C why did you tag C++? Also Mac has its own free IDE called XCode (and debugging in that should be easy enough) - not to mention that there's plenty other options besides CodeBlocks

Comment: @UnholySheep because c plus plus implementation is also same in this case .. except the includes.. and print syntax.. don't have xcode i searched it in launchpad

Comment: If you don't have a debugger, you can always use `printf` statements in your code to tell you what's going on. When you get out into the "real world," you'll have to use that kind of thing a lot.

Comment: "never really understood how to use gdb" - Well, now is a perfect time to learn. SO is not a substitute for learning a debugger. If you are having trouble with gdb, feel free to ask a question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have some problems, and here are few of them:
1. As Jorge mentioned, in your `heapifyUp()` function you never go up, it just stays there and enters infinity loop.
2. In `heapifyDown()` function you have out of bounds problem. You need to check if its children are valid. And it has logic problem.
3. And also, please decide if you want to use 0 indexed array or 1 indexed array. Because some of your functions think it is 0 indexed and some think it is 1 indexed. I made corrections according to 1 indexed array. If you want I can change it to 0 indexed or it could be your homework.

I tried to do my best, but some corrections are still need to be made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 100

int heap[max];
int size = 0;

void heapifyUp(){ // last element
    int i = size;

    while(1){ // 
        int parent = i/2;
        if (parent > 0 && heap[parent] > heap[i]){
            int t = heap[parent];
            heap[parent] = heap[i];
            heap[i]=t;
            i = parent;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void heapifyDown(){ // top element
    int i = 1;

    while(i<size){
        int c1 = 2*i;
        int c2 = 2*i + 1;
        int t;
        if (c1 <= size) {
            t = c1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        if (c2 <= size && heap[c1] > heap[c2]){
            t = c2;
        }

        if(heap[i] >= heap[t]) break;

        int temp = heap[i];
        heap[i] = heap[t];
        heap[t] = temp;
        i = t;
    }
}

void insert(int key){
    size = size + 1;
    heap[size] = key;
    heapifyUp();
}

int returnMin(){
    return heap[1];
}

int deleteMin(){
    int t = heap[1];
    heap[1] = heap[size];
    size = size - 1;
    heapifyDown();
    return t;
}

void printHeap(){
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= size){
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    insert(10);
    insert(20);
    insert(11);
    insert(7);
    insert(18);

    printHeap();
    printf("%d\n",deleteMin());

    insert(110);
    insert(-7);
    insert(15);

    printHeap();
    printf("%d\n",deleteMin());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the indexing is an important note here.  The simpler mathematics for calculating parent indices from child indices and vice-versa rely on a 1-indexed array.

Comment: In my answer I said that you need to decide for indexing but there is nothing to decide. In C programming you always must go with 0.

Comment: I was intending to agree with your statement on indexing in your answer.  However when it comes to indexing in C, while an array is naturally indexed at 0, that is true in how it exists in memory, but there are ways around it.  One could choose to just accept the '0th' element of the as wasted storage and ignore it and instead placing the first element of the heap at the `arr[1]`.  Another way to go about it would be to create a pointer to the memory address one element before your array and this `ptr[1]` will lead you to `arr[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

In heapifyUp you have a `while(i)` statement. "i" gets initialized to 1 and is never modified. And you don't have any "return" or "break" inside that loop. So the condition remains true forever.

Comment: setting i = parent;    in that loop is not not making anything change in the program...

Comment: First of all, I would follow UnholySheep advice and get a free C++ IDE for Mac to be able to debug. It makes things A LOT easier. A debugger is one of the most powerful tools a developer has. Second, I would put `size=size+1` at the end of insert, not at the beginning, because you are lefting 0s in the array (that is seen easily with the debugger). Last, I guess that when the if in heapifyup is true, you want to update i, but when the if is false, maybe you should try returning from that function